# Setting column spacing in Minima CSS framework

Tags: css, jekyll, jekyll-theme, minima

I have Jekyll-based blog hosted on a GitHub page. The blog uses a local copy (hence editable) of the standard Minima theme.

The goal is have a front page layout similar (but not identical to) Google Keep's theme. I'm using a div with "columns: n;" styling to line up the content. The page uses Minima's "default.html" layout file.

[image: front page layout]

I want to reduce the inter-column gaps to some minimum value. Thus far I have tried styling the div with various "column-gap: n" values. No luck.

I'm guessing that Minima's out-of-the-box CSS has an overriding factor, and reviewed the "page-content" and "wrapper" specs, but have not found a way to reduce the column-gap any further than shown.

Suggestions?

Comment: It is difficult to give suggestions without any code to look at.  Do you have a URL to your website or is the website open source?  I suspect you just need to adjust the CSS for `minima` in a certain way.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?